# Pandas GroupBy using another DataFrame of one-hot encodings/overlapping masks

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have two dataframes with observations on rows and features (or group membership) on columns, e.g.:

```
> data_df

     a    b    c
A    1    2    1
B    0    1    3
C    0    0    1
D    2    1    1
E    1    1    1

> mask_df

    g1   g2
A    0    1
B    1    0
C    1    0
D    1    0
E    0    1
```

I want to group and aggregate (by sum) the values in the first dataframe (`data_df`) conditional on the binary values (masks) in the second dataframe (`mask_df`). The result should be the following (groups x features):

```
> aggr_df

     a    b    c
g1   2    2    5
g2   2    3    2
```

Is there a way in pandas to group the first dataframe (`data_df`) using the masks contained in a second dataframe (`mask_df`) in a single command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this cheaply with `dot` and `groupby`:

```
data_df.groupby(mask_df.dot(mask_df.columns)).sum()

    a  b  c
g1  2  2  5
g2  2  3  2
```

Where,

```
mask_df.dot(mask_df.columns)

A    g2
B    g1
C    g1
D    g1
E    g2
dtype: object
```

Which works well assuming each row always has exactly one column set to `1`.

Comment: I thought dot was for matrix multiplication, I'm having trouble following how that would produce the desired result. (This might be how a lack of understanding on how that works under the hood.)

Comment: @Polkaguy6000 pandas `dot` functionality has been extended to work with strings to do cool stuff like this.

Comment: It seems also to work when `mask_df` is a dataframe of booleans

Comment: Unfortunately this (although fast) solution works only with non-overlapping masks, see W-B's or my answer for a more general solution (in the case of sum/mean aggregation).

Comment: @gc5 Nice, thank you for pointing out the distinction. I have upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that this will work even in the case that observations in the first dataframe (`data_df`) belong to multiple masks in the second dataframe (`mask_df`).

```
> pd.concat({x:data_df.mul(mask_df[x],0).sum() for x in mask_df}).unstack()

    a  b  c
g1  2  2  5
g2  2  3  2
```

Comment: This is more general

Comment: However, this is very slow. See my answer for a faster solution in the case of sum/mean aggregation.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to combine the dataframes. You can combine on the index by using a join statement first. `df_merge = data_df.merge(aggr_df, left_on=True, right_on=True)`. Then you can just use `df_merge` for your grouping operations.

Answer (score 2):

I decided to write another answer since:

- [coldspeed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4909087/coldspeed)'s answer works only with one-hot encodings
- [W-B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7964527/w-b)'s answer cannot be easily parallelized since it runs on dict comprehension

In my case I noticed that I could achieve the same result just by using a dot product of `mask_df` with `data_df`:

```
> mask_df.T.dot(data_df)
```

In the special case of getting the average instead of the sum, this is achievable scaling the `mask_df` by the number of ones for each group:

```
> mask_df.T.dot(data_df).div(mask_df.sum(), axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using a list comprehension:

```
pd.DataFrame([(data_df.T * mask_df[i]).sum(axis=1) for i in mask_df.columns], 
             index = mask.columns)

    a  b  c
g1  2  2  5
g2  2  3  2
```